# KeyBoard navigation in Tablayout Tabs

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am trying to implement custom `TabLayout` where Tabs inside a `Tablayout` should have custom background. I want to put focus on a tab item using left/right arrow key.

```
tabView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.tab_item_background,null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.tab_text);
        textView.setText(tab.getText());
        tabView.setFocusable View(true);
        tabView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        tab.setCustomView(tabView);
```

tab_focused.xml

```
    <size android:height="38dp" android:width="40dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/lightest_blue5"/>
```

I am not able to get the focused state when I try to navigate using left/right arrow key. Am I missing something?

1. How to get which `Tab` inside a `Tablayout` has focus?
2. How to forcefully put focus on a `tabItem` inside `TabLayout`?